# Python Selenium HTML class with multiple types and multiple data-binds

Tags: python, html, selenium, data-binding, selenium-webdriver

This is my first day working with Selenium, so I have not picked up all the tricks. I want to use python to populate many different values into text boxes/drop downs from a website. I need to do this many times, and the values will be different each time.

When using Selenium, the majority of what I need to access is in the form:

```
<input class="there are several classes" type="text" data-bind="value: value">
```

Multiple text boxes have the same class, same type but different data-bind values. Every time I try to update values in these text boxes, I am only able to update the first box (and I need access to all text boxes).

The code I've written is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('website')
a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.there.are.several.classes.input-sm")).getAttribute("value")
a.clear()
a.send_keys('0.20')
```

For this code I get AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'

I have also tried:

```
    b = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.there.are.several.classes.input-sm')
    b.clear()
    b.send_keys('2')
```

This works, however it only updates the first text box.  I need a way to access text boxes based on their specific value within the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find_elements_by_css_selector()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) and iterate over the found `input` elements:

```
for elm in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input.there.are.several.classes.input-sm'):
    elm.clear()
    elm.send_keys("2")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 b = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input.there.are.several.classes.input-sm')
```